# Regex to only match ASCII and symbols indicating a new line or paragraph?

Tags: regex, groovy

Essentially, I have email text I want to clean up.

Currently, I'm using:

`body = message?.replaceAll("[^ -~]", "")`

And that is near perfect for my needs - if ONLY I could pick up most of the characters that indicate a new line. (Presently the text is rendered all as one paragraph.)

HTML tags are actually ok for me. It is more the special characters and twitter emojis and so on that concern me. (they are too varied so I would prefer to focus on what I want than what I don't want.)

But best if I could pick up anything that would indicate a new line.

ACTUALLY, I thought my original expression would leave the html tags alone as they are printable characters. I don't quite understand why they were stripped out.

Comment: "*I've searched for a solution*" That's the wrong way to approach a programming problem. Not everything is served on a platter, done for you. You need to do some research, and learn regex for yourself. Show what you have tried, and what isn't working, and then we can talk.

Comment: @RonanKeane Can you show and example of an input an a desired output? :)

Comment: This question shows no working examples. You've shown a function and character replacement but you're not showing a demo of the code you're parsing and the desired result. Maybe the result you want has multiple solutions you haven't considered.

Comment: Too broad. Please give back examples and try to clarify what you want to do, it is impossible for us to help otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that the ASCII symbols for 'new line' (e.g. CR, LF) were also getting stripped out. Simple, but I failed to appreciate it.

The range I was specifying was from - to ~. I needed to specify a broader range. The expression that worked for me was:

```
newtext = text?.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")
```

Comment: Of course, the problem is ALWAYS in asking the correct question. This is the difficult bit for anyone lacking knowledge in an area. 

The question formulation in my OP was actually the result of hours of effort, trial and error and research. I am not a student, so this is time that eats into my productivity. I needed some insight from somebody who recognised something in what I wrote from their own previous experience. 

- In this real world problem, it was not so simple as stating input and desired output. There were "layers" obscuring the discovery of the nub of the problem.

Comment: Not to mention, regex either works or doesn't. So what use is sharing the regex that has utterly failed. Having said that, I do appreciate the time people took to respond, and I apologise for not meeting expected norms. I'm fairly new to StackOverflow. Thank you.